# Freeing dynamic memory

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm just playing around c++ to understand how the memory leak occurs.

```
% g++ --version
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Consider the code below

```
int main() {
const int c=10000;
int* ptrs[c];
for (int n=0; n<c; n++) {
    int s=1000;
    int *x = new int[s];
    for (int i=0; i<s; i++){
        x[i] = i*10;
    }
    ptrs[n] = x;
    //delete[] x; // <-- (1)
}

//Print pointers
for (int n=0; n<c; n++) {
    std::cout << ptrs[n] << std::endl;
    //delete[] ptrs[n]; // <-- (2)
}
std::getchar();
return 0;
```

}

When I check the program memory usage through the task manager at the point where program reaches `std::getchar()` I see that it uses `~360KB` memory when I free up space with `delete[] x;` and `~7.6MB` when doing it by `delete[] ptrs[n];`. My question is why does the second method consume more memory than the first one? They are technically doing the same thing aren't they?

Comment: It is very possible the compiler detects that you are not doing anything with `ptrs` in the first instance, and so just optimizes all the allocation away. Try putting the cout before the first `delete[] x;`

Comment: I don't have a good reason but remember`delete` may not free the memory immediately.  And I don't think task manager is the right tool to check heap usage. You might want to look at heap profilers.

Comment: The C++ memory allocator does not necessarily release memory to the OS when you deallocate it, since most programs are very likely to want to allocate memory again afterwards and reusing it is much faster than doing deallocate/allocate at the OS level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you have implementation defined behaviour, because you inspect a pointer after having called `delete[]` on it. Notwithstanding that, you only have 1000 `int`s in dynamic storage at a time.

In the second case, you have 10000000 `int`s in dynamic storage at the point where you start printing values.

It is likely that your implementation is re-using the same memory over and over.

Comment: seems to be right, I noticed that I get the same allocation address when freeing up space with  `delete[] x;`